# Call a jstl variable inside loop

Tags: jstl, el

I'm iterating well a model object in this way:

```
<c:forEach items="${user[0].periods[0].registers}" var="reg" varStatus="rog">
```

But I want to be able to define over which user iterate, so I add in my code:

```
<c:set var="userid" value="${0}" />
```

With the idea of do:

```
<c:forEach items="${user['${userid.value}'].periods[0].registers}" var="reg" varStatus="rog">
```

But I have an error. I tried multiple ways but I didn'd find the right one.

How can I make a reference to my *userid* value inside c:forecah "${}" sentence?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Map or list, it can be handed in the same way (see duplicate).

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find the answer by myself